# Java Security Settings do not stay changed

Tags: security, java

I have an applet that requires the java security setting to be on medium.  I go into the control panel and change the setting.    I hit apply.   Then exit the Java control panel.   To check if the change stuck, I go in again and check the setting.   It is indeed on medium.   However, as soon as I download my applet into the browser, the setting changes the security setting back to high.    The applet is build on a very early version of 1.6 build 29.   I don't know if this makes a difference or not.

Comment: First question would be what version of 1.6 exactly do you have installed.  Its entirely possible the applet forces the security changes.  I assume you don't have the source to this applet.

Comment: Java 1.6.29 is the version

Comment: That is an extremely hold version.  Have you tried installing a newer version but still running the same application?

Comment: I can't.   The client requires this older version for an application that is not under my control and they will not migrate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had this problem before. First, uninstall all older versions of Java. Then, look for the offline install package on Oracle's website. Run this package, and install it as normal. Then, check for updates and download those. For some reason the offline package seemed to work better for me. I hope the same for you.